# How to get div height after is completely expanded with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, height, console.log

I have read some documentation but I don't have this clear enough.

Let's say I have an image that expands a huge div with class `.content`. I'd like to know how much the `<div class="content">` height, so I do this simple thing inside the function that expands the div

```
contentSize = $('.content').outerHeight(true);
console.log('Content size is', contentSize, 'pixels');
```

use some console logging to see the return but the value is not right. I guess because when the console returns the value the height the div is not completely expanded. Let's say console returns 1500px but the final height is 3000px.

How can I get the right height after the div is completely expanded?

Many thanks

Comment: Can you show the code you used to expand the image?

Comment: Are you using some third party or hide/show or something else to show this?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. 

@Blue Boy, you can see one example here. click in the first image and a div will be expanded. In the console you can find the value that is returned and you will see is not right. http://tanaanstudio.com/again/old/fiddle.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a way to find this. I'm posting here in case someone might find it useful.

In my case, my `<div.content>` was nested in another `<div>` with class `.animator` so if I do this

```
var contentSize = $('.animator').find('.content').outerHeight(true);
console.log('Content size is', contentSize, 'pixels');
```

Then console log returns the right height of `.content`

Cheers